# How do I make a Regex also allow no input?

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4

Allright, so I have a field in my form which is validated with a regular expression.

The following Regex should cover the format I want:

```
(([0-9]+)-([0-9]+):([0-9]+),?)+

Should cover something like this:
100-500:87979,501-789:02020
where repetitions are tolerated if seperated with a comma
```

The thing is, I also want to be able to have **NO** input. Unfortunately my current regular expression doesn't allow for that.

Can anyone give me a hand with making my RegEx allow no input as well?

Answer (score 2):

As a very quick fix, you can optionally take the no input. Try,

```
 ((([0-9]+)-([0-9]+):([0-9]+),?)+|^$)
```